# Are namespaces essential in C#?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I read in http://www.dotnetperls.com/namespace the following:

> Namespaces are not essential for C# programs. They are usually used to
>   make code clearer.

This confused me alot since I had the impession that you should always use a namespace.
I tried to make a win form application from `VS2010` removing the namespace auto generated but the code doesn't compile.

So, my confusion comes to the question:

- When (if) namespaces are essential in a C# Program?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929246/what-is-the-proper-c-sharp-namespace-usage)

Comment: I don't think this is opinion based. They aren't asking whether namespace should be used, they're asking if the have to be.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915033/use-of-namespaces-in-c-sharp Look at Eric Answer.

Comment: Well I'll be joining in the close vote, as in my opinion, they should never not be used. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write C# programs without namespaces, but you cannot access the .NET framework without them. So you actually do really need them.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried to make a win form application

The standard mistake to make here is that you removed the namespace from the `YourForm.cs` source code file but you forgot to do the same thing for the `YourForm.Designer.cs` file.  Editing the Designer.cs file like that is okay.  But of course adds more FUD to what you are trying to do.

There just isn't a wholeheckofalot of point to fighting the machine.  Microsoft likes you to use namespaces for a good reason, they are good to avoid identifier name collisions and find a workaround when they happen anyway.  You can spell the name in full.  You have no such workaround available if your identifiers are all in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I should recommend you to read this [article from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx)

you can see the following:

> Whether or not you explicitly declare a namespace in a C# source file, the compiler adds a default namespace.

My recomendation to you is that you use it when you need to organize your code, example: you have 2 different types of model and you don't want them to share code

Comment: Did you mean "you don't want theM to share the code"? I'm a self-taught semi-senior programmer who is seriously trying to guess the relevance of namespaces to keep code clean, and if I should start making namespaces myself... ultimately I'm all obsessed about Design Patterns and Refactoring Techniques...

Comment: precisely, my bad, didn't see the typo there. Ultimately you can look to Namespaces as an organizational tool, where you know that a certain model for could be under the namespace NameOfTheProgram.Models, or you can even go further and have it in NameOfTheProgram.Models.NameOfTheBusinessLogic

Comment: In that sense, it works more or less like Python's modules when importing (more or less), doesn't it? But declaring the namespaces and stuff probably needs a concrete methodology... anyway, I will keep your words in mind... so, the next time I use namespaces with C#, I have to see them like "modules" to keep everything organized.